# R: How do I change cell value of a dataframe created via a variable in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, variables

I need to update a cell value of a data frame created via a variable in a for loop

**Create Dafaframe**

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = c(rep(1,9)),
  col2 = c(rep(2,9)),
  col3= c(rep(3, 9))
)
df
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2    3
2    1    2    3
3    1    2    3
4    1    2    3
5    1    2    3
6    1    2    3
7    1    2    3
8    1    2    3
9    1    2    3
```

**Split into 3 dataframes i.e df1,df2,df3**
The actual data set is more complex , however, the goal is to update the split dataframes i.e. df1-3 within the for loop. This is because my data set is very large.

I tried the commented line of code but it gave me a new variable with the respective name in the paste function assigning it a value 0

```
for(i in seq(1,3,1)){
  if (i == 1) {
  assign(paste0("df",i),df[1:3,])
  #assign(paste0("df",i,"$col2[1]"),0)
  }
  if (i == 2 ){
  assign(paste0("df",i),df[4:6,])
  #assign(paste0("df",i,"$col2[1]"),0)
  }
  if (i == 3 ){
  assign(paste0("df",i),df[7:9,])
  #assign(paste0("df",i,"$col2[1]"),0)
  } 
}

df1
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2    3
2    1    2    3
3    1    2    3
```

**Expected output**
I need to use the for loop to update the first row in col2 of each of the split dataframes to 0.

```
df1
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    0    3
2    1    2    3
3    1    2    3
Same for df2 and df3
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the for loop? I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I'm 99% sure a for loop is the wrong way to go about it. Also, "assign" is best avoided.

Comment: I am trying to create multiple dataframes from the main dataframe. After which I want to update a cell in each of the smaller dataframes. In practice, my dataframe as well over 70k rows. I understand the sequence to split into smaller dataframes. However,  I struggle to achieve the result in the "expected output" section in an automated manner i.e. without explicitely writing a command for each of the smaller dataframes created within the loop

Comment: 70k rows isn't that much - there's no inherent reason why you can't just use your dataframe as is. Anyway, look at my suggested solution below and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

May I offer an alternative approach? Instead of creating several different data.frames, create a list of data.frames (using `split`). Then you can use `lapply` to make the same change in each of the dataframe elements:

```
lapply(split(df,paste0("df",rep(1:3,each=3))),function(x) {x[1,2]<-0;x})

$df1
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    0    3
2    1    2    3
3    1    2    3

$df2
  col1 col2 col3
4    1    0    3
5    1    2    3
6    1    2    3

$df3
  col1 col2 col3
7    1    0    3
8    1    2    3
9    1    2    3
```

If, for whatever reason, you absolutely insist on starting out with a for-loop to create the dataframes (which I seriously advise against), you can then place them all into a list using `lapply(paste0("df",1:3),get)`, and wrap that with the `lapply` I suggested above, to get the same result (but without the helpful element names of each of the dataframes in the list).

Comment: Thanks iod. However, this doesnt directly help me. Like I mentioned the conditions to split are complex and different from using a simple rep() to split. can you perharps suggest a different way to mak e the commented line ofcode work i.e. #assign(paste0("df",i,"$col2[1]"),0)

Comment: Whatever the conditions are, you can still use `split` to create it (split uses a factor vector as the splitting guide, so you can create whatever vector that can be coerced into a factor to determine the splitting). Like I said, the commented line is just not an advisable way of doing things.

Comment: also, see added option at the bottom of my solution.

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, please don't forget to accept and upvote!